# How to process many tables using AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, data-lake, aws-glue-spark

As part of doing data validation I have use-case of processing many tables. Number of tables are almost 2000. Due to tight SLA there is a need now to process many tables concurrently.
Due to Glue concurrency limit of 50 (which I got increased to 100 by raising a support ticket. They cannot increase further as 100 is the hard limit for my AWS region).
Is there a better way of processing my data?